# How can I add datetime to an existing file name in Linux?

Tags: shell, variable-substitution

I want to add date and time to the file name, for example: `08032016out.log.zip`

This is what I try to do:

```
_now=$(date +"%m_%d_%Y")
_file="$_nowout.log"
touch $_file.txt # creating new file with the timedate
```

How can I create the new file with the datetime?

Comment: I very strongly recommend using YYYYMMDD rather than DDMMYYYY.  YYYYMMDD is the **only** format that sorts correctly, which (along with the fact that it's unambiguous) is why it's the ISO standard recommended date format (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Answer (score 14):

You have created a variable named `_now`, but later you reference a variable named `_nowout`. To avoid such issues, use curly braces to delimit variable names:

```
_now=$(date +"%m_%d_%Y")
_file="${_now}out.log"
touch "$_file.txt"
```

Note that I have left `"$_file.txt"` as is, because `.` is already a variable names delimiter. When in doubt, `"${_file}.txt"` could be used just as well.

Bonus 1: `${varname}` syntax actually provides several useful [string operations](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/8919) on variables, in addition to delimiting.

Bonus 2: creative shell escaping and quoting can also be used to delimit variable names. You could quote the variable and the string literal separately (i.e. `file="$_now""out.log"` or `file="$_now"'out.log'`) or leave one of the parts unquoted (i.e. `file=$_now"out.log"` or `file="$_now"out.log`). Finally, you can escape a single character which follows your variable name: `file=$_now\out.log`. Though I wouldn't recommend reusing these examples without good understanding of shell quoting and escaping rules.

Comment: Note that you could also do `file="$_now"'out.log'` or `file=$_now\out.log`, that is using quoting operators would also delimit variables (`${var}` is a lot better/canonical though)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas useful suggestion, thanks. I'll mention it in my answer.

Answer (score 9):

You need to specify the boundaries of the variable name.

`_file` will be set to `$_nowout.log` but the shell can not determine if you mean `$_now` or `$_nowout`.

Use

```
_file="${_now}out.log"
```

to explicitly use the `$_now` variable.

So the script becomes:

```
_now=$(date +"%m_%d_%Y")
_file="${_now}out.log"
touch "${_file}.txt"
```

Which, for the record can be shortened to:

```
touch "$(date +%m_%d_%Y)out.txt"
```